# Put into array using for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, double

I am thinking of finding an easy way to put numbers into an array using a for loop. I have made the easy design with text showing how the name system works!

My code is like this:

```
double[,] kast = new double[3, 8];
string[] navn = new string[8];
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnSorter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 1; i > 4; i++)
    {
        for(int x = 1; i > 9; i++)
        {
            kast[i, x] = Convert.ToDouble(txtKast + i + x + .Text);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how I will make it work with the `Convert.ToDouble` part since "kast" is a double array.

Comment: Check your loop conditions.

Comment: Yeah good call, `i > 4`.  Also your inner loop is incrementing the outer loop?

Comment: It is c# im sorry i forgot. I don't know what you mean by the inner loop incrementing the outer loop?

Comment: [C# for loop reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)